# Mouseover text then Change Image not Working in IE8-below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a banner made out of JavaScript wherein when you hover a particular text the image in the banner changes.

I was wondering how to make it compatible in ie8..

I used this tutorial to come up with the js:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/rolldifferent.shtml

I'm also trying to mouse out too then the image will change.

Here are the js codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function changeimage(towhat,url){if (document.images){document.images.targetimage.src=towhat.src gotolink=url}}functionwarp({window.location=gotolink}</script>

<script>var myimages=new Array()var gotolink="#"function preloadimages(){for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){myimages[i]=newImage()myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i]}}preloadimages("map_wm_hover.gif", "map_wm_hover2.gif","map_wm.gif")</script>
```

Here is the css:

```
<div id="base"><div id="mapcontainer"><a href="javascript:warp()"><img src="map_wm.gif" name="targetimage" border=0></a></div>


<div id="textcontainer"><div class="textboxinner1"><a href="index.html"onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[2],this.href)">8CCC REQUESTS/TALKBACK</a></div>

<div class="textboxinner2"><a href="index.html"onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[1],this.href)">Alice Springs  8952 7771</a></div>

<div class="textboxinner2"><a href="index.html"onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[0],this.href)">Tenant Creek 8952 7182</a></div>

<div class="textboxinner3"><span class="t3nonelink">...other contact details <a href="index.html" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[2],this.href)">here</a></span></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code here instead of links?

Comment: As far as I can see both examples work in IE8. The images change when you hover. I think the problem you are referring to may be that one of the gifs is animated and the animation doesn't work in IE?

Comment: Yes stuart that is correct. Actually the animated gifs are not working in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with IE where animated gifs are not loaded properly in javascript. A workaround is to put the images in a hidden div in the HTML code instead of loading them in the script. A positive side-effect is that this greatly simplifies the javascript. See http://jsfiddle.net/5pZLT/7

HTML:

```
<DIV id=base>
    <DIV id=mapcontainer><A href="javascript:warp()"><IMG border=0 name=targetimage src ="http://www.keencloudmedia.com/skybluekangaroo/map_wm.gif"></A> </DIV>
<DIV id=textcontainer>
<DIV class=textboxinner1><A onmouseover=changeimage(2,this.href) 
href="index.html">8CCC REQUESTS/TALKBACK</A> </DIV>
<DIV class=textboxinner2><A onmouseover=changeimage(1,this.href) 
href="index.html">Alice Springs 8952 7771</A> </DIV>
<DIV class=textboxinner2><A onmouseover=changeimage(0,this.href) 
href="index.html">Tenant Creek 8952 7182</A> </DIV>
<DIV class=textboxinner3><SPAN class=t3nonelink>...other contact details <A 
onmouseover=changeimage(2,this.href) href="index.html">here</A></SPAN> 
    </DIV></DIV></DIV><div id="hiddenImages" style="display: none">
<img src="http://www.keencloudmedia.com/skybluekangaroo/map_wm_hover.gif" name="hoverImage" />
<img src="http://www.keencloudmedia.com/skybluekangaroo/map_wm_hover2.gif" name="hoverImage2" />
<img src="http://www.keencloudmedia.com/skybluekangaroo/map_wm.gif" name="originalImage" />
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
var gotolink = "#";
function changeimage(imageNumber, url) {
    if (document.images) {
        document.images.targetimage.src = 
            document.getElementById('hiddenImages').children[imageNumber].src;
        gotolink = url;
    }
}
```

By the way there were lots of ;s missing in your original code which would tend to stop it working.

Comment: Hi Stuart! Thanks a lot for this. I'm going to try this out. I'm pretty much a noob with js that's why I rely on tutorials for now.